# How to do conditional replace value in data

Tags: r

I have below data table and want to replace other than Web,Mobile usage into another category say others. (OR) 
Is there anyway group the usage as Web, Mobile and rest all as others without replace the value like Web is used 1 , Mobile 1 and Others - 4 (OR)

Do we need to write a function to do so.

```
Id   Name    Usage
 1    AAA      Web
 2    BBB   Mobile
 3    CCC   Manual
 4    DDD       M1
 5    EEE       M2
 6    FFF       M3
```

Comment: simple ifelse() shall do the job!

Comment: df$Usage <- ifelse(df$Usage %in% c("Web", "Mobile"), df$Usage, "Others")

Comment: If `Usage` is a character variable: `df[!df$Usage %in% c('Web', 'Mobile'), 'Usage'] <- 'Others'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the 'Usage' is `character` class, we can use `%chin%` to create a logical index, negate it (`!`) and assign (`:=`) values in 'Usage' to 'Others'.  This would be more efficient as we are assigning in place without any copying.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[!Usage %chin% c("Web", "Mobile"), Usage := "Others"]
df1
#   Id. Name  Usage
#1:   1  AAA    Web
#2:   2  BBB Mobile
#3:   3  CCC Others
#4:   4  DDD Others
#5:   5  EEE Others
#6:   6  FFF Others
```